# Why am I often getting error 0x8007000e when debugging a project in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis

I have a Visual Studio 2008 project that is proving difficult to debug. I need to attach to IIS 7 to debug it. At least 50% of the time I get the following error shortly after attaching to w3wp.exe:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated.
For more details, please see the Microsoft Help and Support web site.
HRESULT=0x8007000e. ErrorCode=0x0.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

It then terminates w3wp.exe.

I don't get this problem with any other solution. Any ideas on how to fix this please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you Google this error you'll find a lot of information about it.

0x8007000e = The application is out of memory. Perhaps your computer does not have enough RAM and/or disk space.

Comment: Just to add, this link http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/296622/fatal-error-debugging-hresult-0x8007000e might be relevant as well

Comment: There were at least 20 projects in the solution and while I didn't think this was the issue, unloading a whole heap of them and restarting seemed to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is also an issue with Visual Studio 2012 on a console project. Oddly enough the same projects in Visual studio 2010 do not cause the same issue.

Whereas it didn't provide the information I needed, I found that you can launch without debugging and then attach the debugger to the process to gain access to your breakpoints without triggering the error.

For what its worth, I have noticed in a few posts online that people who are experiencing the issue tend to have multiple projects within the solution (including the OP).

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue when I was working with web services based application.
I used **Visual Studio 2012 + Win 7 (32bit) OS**.

**NONE** of the solutions that I found with google has worked for me (wasn't a RAM or disk space problem).

The only solution that worked for me: installing **Win 7 64 bit** OS.

*Just backup your data & install 64bit OS + apply latest Win Updates.*