# What is this error "A fatal error has occurred HRESULT=0x8007000e. Error Code=0x0" in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2

While i am trying to run a MVC 2 application in VS 2008 i am getting following error:

A fatal error has occurred HRESULT=0x8007000e. Error Code=0x0

can any one explain what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

An `HRESULT` has three parts: some flags, a "facility" and the error code.

0x8007000e

- 8: Error
- 7: `FACILITY_WIN32`: ie. this is a Windows error.
- E: or 14: ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY

So you process or system is overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [Why am I often getting error 0x8007000e when debugging a project in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038884/why-am-i-often-getting-error-0x8007000e-when-debugging-a-project-in-visual-studio)

Additional info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/56e15831-5729-4775-be09-d565fca19605