# Unable to debug application in visual studio 2010 after install visual studio 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

After the installment of visual studio 2013 i'm having problems to debug the 'bigger' applications of visual studio 2010.

I'm getting the following Error:

```
A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated. For more details, please see the
Microsoft Help and Support web site. HRESULT=0x8007000e. ErrorCode=0x0.
```

**Reading about the error points me in a lack of physical memory. Yet I have 16 GB ram of which 20% is used at the moment and still 300 gigs of diskspace free.So it can't be a memory problem**

I know there are many questions persent with regards to this error message. Yet none deviate from the base conclusion of lack of memory. Whereas in my case there is still lots of memory available.

Any ideas/suggestions/tips are very welcome

***Note: subset of Searched info***

[Social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/56e15831-5729-4775-be09-d565fca19605/a-fatal-error-has-occurred-hresult0x8007000e-error-code0x0?forum=vsdebug)

[Why am I often getting error 0x8007000e when debugging a project in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038884/why-am-i-often-getting-error-0x8007000e-when-debugging-a-project-in-visual-studi)

[what-is-this-error-a-fatal-error-has-occurred-hresult-0x8007000e-error-code-0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351829/what-is-this-error-a-fatal-error-has-occurred-hresult-0x8007000e-error-code-0x)

[atal-error-debugging-hresult-0x8007000e](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/296622/fatal-error-debugging-hresult-0x8007000e)

***Note 2:*** Simply upgrading to visual studio 2013 is not a possibility at the moment.

***Note3*** : According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407021(VS.100).aspx) site the limit of virtual memory for VS is at 2 gigs. Yet the program itself never even reaches 1 gig (viewed in task manager) and using the command `bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVa 3072` i've already increased it to 3 gigs

***Note 4:*** During the debug in VS2013 we notice a sudden spike of 300 mb for a second or 2 when starting to debug. So obviously the error could be correct but the reason is stillwhat blurry.

Comment: what about your os drive space?

Comment: That is the one with the 300 gigs of free space. other drives have even more free space. Yet the issue only started occuring after the installment of vs2013 without any modifications to the actual code

Comment: Is it possible to put System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); somewhere in the startup code, and then run the app NOT under vs2010 debugger? Doing so should give you a dialog and allow you to attach a debugger (including VS2013) of choice, which might work?

Comment: @simonatrcl sweet! Great idea. If i attach a VS2013 debugger than no more problems! Can you post it as answer so i'll approve it? Thnx for the effort!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to put System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); somewhere in the startup code, and then run the app NOT under vs2010 debugger? Doing so should give you a dialog and allow you to attach a debugger (including VS2013) of choice, which might work?

Glad it helped :)

PS Might be worth trying to re-install VS2010? Also, put #If DEBUG..#Endif either side of the Debugger.Launch() line so it won't do it in Release!