# How to resolve conflicts between Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have a Windows application written in `Visual Studio 2010`. It connects to a web service and does other database calls as well.

When I installed `Visual Studio 2012` the above mentioned app doesn't work anymore.  I thought that something was broken or that there were maybe conflicts between 2010 and 2012.  So just to be sure I uninstalled all my Visual Studios and reinstalled Visual Studio 2010.  I tried to run the app again and it worked 100%.  I then reinstalled Visual Studio 2012 and the app doesn't run.  It comes up with the following error:

```
A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated. For more details, please the Microsoft Help and Support web site. HRESULT=0x8007000e. ErrorCode=0x0.
```

Why would I be getting this error?  How do I resolve this?

My app can't be out of memory as I have about 4GB and that is sufficient when it runs without Visual Studio 2012 installed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038884/why-am-i-often-getting-error-0x8007000e-when-debugging-a-project-in-visual-studi

Comment: Some causes are described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425475/can-visual-studio-2012-be-installed-side-by-side-w-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 4.5 is an “in place upgrade” to .NET Framework 4.0. Some files were probably upgraded that’s may be the reason.
see the link for details [vs2010 v/s vs2012](http://kupsidoo.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/dont-install-visual-studio-2012-with-visual-studio-2010/)